# How to start GVim on Windows with vimfiles at custom location?

Tags: windows, vim

I am using Cygwin most of the time with my vimfiles on `/usr/share/vim8/` and my runtimefiles at `%HOME%\.vim`.

I installed GVim for Windows and I would like to use the Vim files from Cygwin. When I start GVim it cannot find the `runtimefiles`. How can I configure it?

It does find my `.vimrc` tough.

Comment: The default runtime (`$VIMRUNTIME`, what you refer to as "vimfiles") is tailored to the installed Vim version. Why would you want to redirect GVIM to a different one (as it already comes with its own)? This is just inviting trouble...

Comment: It does not because you can just download the executable `ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim80-586.zip`. This is what I want since I already have the runtime files installed with Cygwin. It is pointless to have twice the same folder.

Comment: That's not a complete installer (`README_bindos.txt` says: _You MUST also get the runtime archive (vim80rt.zip)_)!

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried so far? This should be possible via `:set runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim8,~/.vim/after` in your `~/.vimrc`, but again, I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share the configuration between Vim in Cygwin and native GVim, you could create a NTFS symlink from the Cygwin `$HOME/vim` directory to the Windows `%HOMEPATH%` directory. I use the same set of configuration files for Vim regardless of whether it’s running on a GNU/Linux system, Cygwin or native Windows. Here’s the Windows command that I used to create my NTFS symlink (with Windows 7, the `mklink` command must be run in a command window with [elevated privileges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link#Restrictions)).

```
mklink /D %HOMEPATH%\vimfiles C:\cygwin64\home\anthony\.vim
```

Also, instead of using `_vimrc` (MS Windows)`or ~/.vimrc` (Unix-like) for the primary vimrc, I use `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`. With the above symlink, this will automatically be found (and used) by GVim as `$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`.

For configuration settings that only apply in a Windows environment, you can include a configuration block in your `vimrc` similar to the following:

```
if has("win32") || has("win64")
    set guifont=Consolas:h10:cANSI
    " Other Windows-specific configurations, e.g., key mappings
    source $VIM\_vimrc
endif
```